# snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 250003 (08001): 429 Too Many Requests: post https://coxauto.okta.com/api/v1/authn"

Tags: python, multithreading, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, concurrent.futures, connector

I'm querying snowflake using multi-threading in python using the concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor, but getting a "Too Many Requests" error.  I"m trying to figure out how to work around this and maximize my multi-threading capacity.

My syntax was

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# task function
def task(value):
    return result from snowflake

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
    inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    result = {d : r for d,r in zip(inputs, exe.map(task, inputs))}
```

But I get the 429 "Too many requests" error..

"snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 250003 (08001): 429 Too Many Requests: post [https://coxauto.okta.com/api/v1/authn"](https://coxauto.okta.com/api/v1/authn%22)

Comment: do you know how many queries it takes to start getting this error?

Comment: 1 call to task, 3 calls to Snowflake - Success.
2 calls to task, 6 calls to Snowflake - Success.
3 calls to task, 11 calls to Snowflake - Success.
4 call to task, 15 calls to Snowflake - Crash before completion w/error msg.

Comment: It looks to me you're sending too many requests to your Okta IDP, are you using externalbrowser authentication? This doesn't seem it's a 429 from Snowflake but rather your Okta IDP.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Maybe I'll try to check whether that might be the case.  In the meantime, I avoid the error if I use up to 4 threads.  "with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as exe..." I get the error.